# Copy parent element that contains specific child element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a simple xml:

```
<custom-objects>
    <custom-object id="1">
        <object-attribute attribute-id="address1">Warndtstr. 33</object-attribute>
        <object-attribute attribute-id="branch">01</object-attribute>
        <object-attribute attribute-id="catalogid">7991</object-attribute>
        <object-attribute attribute-id="exportdate">2015-09-19</object-attribute>
    </custom-object>
    <custom-object>
...
    </custom-object>
</custom-objects>
```

I'm trying to simply copy every `<custom-object>` element which contains a child where `@attribute-id` is `"exportdate"` and has a specific textvalue.

Here is my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="custom-object[object-attribute[@attribute-id='exportdate']='2015-09-19']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The match is working when using as xpath. The xslt returns an empty result.

- Why is it not working in this case?
- Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I'm trying to simply copy every element which contains a child where @attribute-id is "exportdate" and has a specific textvalue."*

Empty template supposed to be used for deleting elements. So currently, your XSL should remove `custom-object` where 'exportdate' equals '2015-09-19', and copy other elements. If you want the opposite, try using XPath with the opposite meaning, for example :

```
<xsl:template 
    match="custom-object[not(object-attribute[@attribute-id='exportdate']='2015-09-19')]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Another short question: How to match childs where textvalue is beginning with/containing '2015-'? Is there a way to use regex?

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 you can use `starts-with()` or `contains()` function