# Is there a way in XSLT to create take a section of a huge XML based on a single node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML that looks like the following:

```
<xml>
     <agreement>
          <country>Canada</country>
          <state>Ontario</state>
          <person>
               <name>Mark</name>
          </person>
     </agreement>
     <agreement>
          <country>USA</country>
          <state>Alabama</state>
          <person>
               <name>John</name>
          </person>
     </agreement>
     <agreement>
          <country>United Kingdom</country>
          <state></state>
          <person>
               <name>Eric</name>
          </person>
     </agreement>
</xml>
```

I now need to generate a xml that only shows everything under agreement when the country is Canada. Is there a way for me to do this in XSLT?

Output:

```
<xml>
     <agreement>
          <country>Canada</country>
          <state>Ontario</state>
          <person>
               <name>Mark</name>
          </person>
     </agreement>
</xml>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy parent element that contains specific child element using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132078/copy-parent-element-that-contains-specific-child-element-using-xslt)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xml>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xml/agreement[country='Canada']"/>
        </xml>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="agreement">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or shortly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="agreement[country='Canada']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```